# How to define an array as a data type and push an integer value in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Actually I'm using MySql as a db in Node.js. My app is basically allows users to like the post that others share, so I want to store users IDs that liked the post into an array as a data type, but I'm finding trouble defining the right data type and then push the new user id into that array in mysql query.
I almost spent the whole day looking for my answer but unfortunately i always come across PHP code ! Hopefully someone could give the correct answer.

This is a part of my code :

```
db.query('CREATE TABLE post_likes (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,
likes INT,
post_id INT,
users_liked JSON'));


// All the values of these variables are numerical values
const { like, post_id, user_id } = req.body;

db.query('UPDATE post_likes SET likes = likes + ?, users_liked = users_liked + ?  WHERE post_id = ?',like, user_id, post_id, (err, result)=>{
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send(err);
                    }
                    res.status(200).json({ message: "Added a like!" });
```

Comment: If you need to store an array of integers then you may use JSON column and store JSON array in it. On recent versions you can even index it.

Comment: I've already defined my column "users_liked" as a json data type but i don’t know how to push the new user id to that column !

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-preserve